# Angular 2 TestModuleMetadata does not have an EntryComponents property

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm using Angular CLI 1.0.0-beta.32.2 and am writing a unit test for an Angular 2 service, which dynamically creates a Component and inserts it into another Component.

In my unit test I try to create a mock component to test my service, but the output of `ng test` throws an error, stating my mock Component is specified in the `entryComponents` property. When I try to add the Component into an `entryComponents` property of the TestModuleMetadata object, like this: `TestBed.createTestingModule({...entryComponents:  [ TestDialogComponent ]...})` I see the following error stating the `entryComponents` property does not exist.

`Chrome 56.0.2924 (Windows 10 0.0.0) DialogService should create a child component when opening FAILED
Error: No component factory found for TestDialogComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?`

Looking at the TestModuleMetadata definition shows that the entryComponents property does not exist. So how do I go about dynamically creating a Component in my unit tests in Angular 2 and Jasmine?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As far as i know it has not supported yet. As workaround you can create fake module with `entryComponent` and import it to your testing module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [TestDialogComponent],
  entryComponents: [TestDialogComponent]
})
export class FakeTestDialogModule {}
```

and then

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [FakeTestDialogModule]
```

Comment: That fixed it, thank you! I've found an open issue regarding the omission of the `entryComponents` property in the TestModuleMetadata, [ComponentFactoryResolver is not aware of components compiled via TestBed](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10760)

Answer (score 3):

Check `TestBed.overrideModule`. Please refer to this discussion 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12079

I got the error for my `DialogBoxComponent`. I resolved it as follows

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ NewPracticeQuestionComponent,
      DialogBoxComponent,
        ShowErrorsComponent],
      imports:[ReactiveFormsModule,HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers:[WebToBackendInterfaceService,HelperService,AuthService]
    })

    TestBed.overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, {
      set: {
        entryComponents: [DialogBoxComponent]
      }
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```